# Bash- Running a command on each grep correspondence without stopping tail -n0 -f

Tags: bash, grep, pipe, tail

I'm currently monitoring a log file and my ultimate goal is to write a script that uses `tail -n0 -f` and execute a certain command once `grep` finds a correspondence. My current code:

```
tail -n 0 -f $logfile | grep -q $pattern && echo $warning > $anotherlogfile
```

This works but only once, since grep -q stops when it finds a match. The script must keep searching and running the command, so I can update a status log and run another script to automatically fix the problem. Can you give me a hint?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use a while loop

```
tail -n 0 -f "$logfile" | while read LINE; do
    echo "$LINE" | grep -q "$pattern" && echo "$warning" > "$anotherlogfile"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

`awk` will let us continue to process lines and take actions when a pattern is found.  Something like:

```
tail -n0 -f "$logfile" | awk -v pattern="$pattern" '$0 ~ pattern {print "WARN" >> "anotherLogFile"}'
```

If you need to pass in the warning message and path to `anotherLogFile` you can use more `-v` flags to `awk`.  Also, you could have `awk` take the action you want instead. It can run commands via the `system()` function where you pass the shell command to run

Comment: Thanks for the input @Eric Renouf. Your code works but once I clean my "anotherlogfile", it won't write on the log again. So it only works once.

Comment: @madsantos do you need to have multiple entries in `anotherlogfile` or is it enough to have a single warning in it at a time?  If so, try replacing `>>` with `>` and see if that helps